# PagedList in MVC: Loading with Ajax and cannot preserve search terms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have googled around, and while a couple of people have asked this question, nobody that I have found has posted a working solution.

I am using the PagedList package in order to create pages in my MVC application.  I am loading the pages via Ajax.  The problem is that I cannot preserve my search terms (changing the page acts like nothing was ever filtered).

Here is my method:

```
public PartialViewResult Search(string q, int? page, int? pageSize)
{
    ViewBag.SearchQuery = q;
    //Searching and sorting logic, not really relevant
    return PartialView("_SearchedTable", listObj.ToPagedList((int)page, (int)pageSize));
}
```

If I look at the ViewBag.SearchQuery item in the partial view, I can see it and it is what I expect.  But whenever I change the page, everything that is sent to the controller is null.  Here is my page item

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Search",
    new { q = ViewBag.SearchQuery, page = page }), 
    PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(
        new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "main-table"}))
```

Looking at intellisense in the debugger, everything has the value that I expect, up until this element sends data off to the Search method again, in which case it all comes out of the search method as "null".  When I was not using Ajax, and had it calling the full Index view method on every page change, it was preserving searching fine.  The only thing I added was the third parameter, which enables unobtrusive ajax and the ajax options.

EDIT: I solved by placing the HTML helper in the partial view, so that it would be executed on every refresh.  Otherwise, the anchor tags that the @Url.Action() method generates would never change, and since the first time loading the page everything is null, they were never updated when search terms were entered.

Comment: yes, are you mentioned the div?

Comment: show some more code
and Try
`@Html.PagedListPager(Model.MovieInforamtions, page => Url.Action("GetMovieDatabase", page }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing( new AjaxOptions(){  HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "movie_grid"}))`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.MovieInforamtions, page => Url.Action("GetMovieDatabase", page }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing( new AjaxOptions(){  HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "movie_grid"}))
```

the comment from @arjit helped to solve a similar issue. where movie_grid is the id of a DIV...